# How send key value in addMultipartParts Ion Koush library?

Tags: android, laravel, laravel-5, android-ion, ion-koush

I'm using the **Ion Koush Library** in my android project, it is working fine but I don't know how to specify the key request when I use the `addMultipartParts` function.

My code:

```
Ion.with(this)
   .load("POST", UPLOADIMAGESTG_URL)
   .setTimeout(5000)
   .setMultipartParameter("omni_id", String.valueOf(omniTesteGrade.getOmniProduct().get_id()))
   .addMultipartParts(files)
   .asJsonObject()
   .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {


    @Override        
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                if (e != null) {
                    pDialog.setTitleText("Não foi possível enviar imagens, enviando dados do produto");
                    sendTgToServer(json);
                } else {
                    pDialog.setTitleText("Enviando dados do produto");
                    sendTgToServer(json);
                }
            }

   });
```

It is working fine on the server side because I pick all the inputs with a `laravel` function `Input::All()`. But when I want to pick specific request I use this code

```
   foreach($fileObjects as $fileObject) {
            if (is_file($fileObject)) {
                $imageList[] =$fileObject;
            } else {
                $id = $fileObject;
            }
   }
```

And this is wrong one more process to server work and I don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

The things are not pretty clear from your questions, that you want to upload a single Image file to the server or Multiple files to the server.

So basically, there is a very simple way you can achieve this thing.

1. **To upload a single file:-**

   ```
   Ion.with(this)  
   .load("POST", UPLOADIMAGESTG_URL)  
   .uploadProgressBar(uploadProgressBar)   
   .setTimeout(5000)   
   .setMultipartParameter("omni_id", String.valueOf(omniTesteGrade.getOmniProduct().get_id()))  
   .setMultipartFile("key to upload image", new File(files))  
   .asJsonObject()  
   .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() { 
   @Override        
   public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {  

               if (e != null) {
                   pDialog.setTitleText("Não foi possível enviar imagens, enviando dados do produto");
                   sendTgToServer(json);
               } else {
                   pDialog.setTitleText("Enviando dados do produto");
                   sendTgToServer(json);
               }
    });
   ```
2. **To upload multiple files:-**

ArrayList fileParts = new ArrayList<> ();

```
for (int i = 0; i < salonPhotos.size(); i++) {
   Part part = new FilePart("image_name[" + i + "]", image_value[i]);
   fileParts.add(part);
}


Ion.with(getContext())
   .load("POST", MY_POST_URL)
   .setMultipartParameter("my_text_key", "my_text_value")
   .setMultipartParameter("my_text_key_2", "my_text_value_2")
   .addMultipartParts(fileParts);
```

Try this, May it help you.

Comment: Thank you, Abhinav for the answer to my question.

The problem is that I want to upload Multiple files to the server and in the function from Ion Library that was made for that "addMultipartParts" don't have a parameter to put a key

Like setMultipartFile have.

Comment: you can check the answers, I have edited now and also look for the backend code how they are providing some support to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you Abhinav.

But i already have sending multiple files at once, my problem is in the serverside

Because when i send multiple i cannot put a KEY to identify the array of files in serverside you get now?

Because of that i use this function

  foreach($fileObjects as $fileObject) {
            if (is_file($fileObject)) {
                $imageList[] =$fileObject;
            } else {
                $id = $fileObject;
            }
   }

but i don't want use that you undestand now?

Comment: Ok, So you are basically looking for the backend code that gonna work with this things,   
Right??